# what is the reason behind using student.num_student in the above program why not only use num_student=num_student+1?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

```
class student:
    num_student=0
    class_teacher="Mr Yamasito"

    def __init__(self,rno,name,mks):
        self.rollno=rno
        self.name=name
        self.marks=mks
        self.grade="A"
        #print(num_student)
        student.num_student=num_student+1
```

Comment: when you add the `student.` you are referencing the variable statically

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion would not have worked:

```
class student:
    num_student = 0

    def __init__(self):
        num_student = num_student + 1

student()
# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num_student' referenced before assignment
```

Also, it will be better to use `self.__class__.num_student` instead of `student.num_student` in order to better support subclassing.

Comment: I think it's `student.num_student` because it's meant be static so it can keep track of how many `student` objects are initialized.

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding what you mean, I don't think you're correct. If it were `self.num_student = self.num_student + 1` then each `student` instance would have a `num_student` value of `1`.

Comment: @mypetlion, Indeed. Should have been `self.__class__`. I'll fix the answer. The correct way to implement this is a  metaclass anyway..